# Auto Fill combo box is taking full page of size when we press drop down. Need to limit it to top 5 values. without doing query change

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, combobox, autofill

I need a little help here with auto fill combo box which will display all the vehicles which are owned by Company.
Please check the screen shot and code and guide me to how to limit the display items in number of 5 so that combo box does not take the full size of page.
I don't want to change anything in query, i want to set it from the code or any available property which can limit it (Note : MaximumDropDownItems is already at 8 still it takes full page). The drop down menu must drop on bottom of the combo box not on upper side of it.

Thanks

Screen Shot

[image]

The code for auto fill is as follow :

```
Dim v As New VehicleMast
        dt = v.getvhcl("select Vehicle_NO from MastVehicle")

        If com_vhcl_no.InvokeRequired Then
            com_vhcl_no.BeginInvoke(New loadVehicleDel(AddressOf loadVehicleSub), cmd, dt)
        Else
            For Each q In dt.Rows
                com_vhcl_no.Items.Add(q("Vehicle_NO"))
            Next

            With com_vhcl_no
                '.DataSource = dt
                .DisplayMember = "Vehicle_NO"
                .ValueMember = "Vehicle_NO"
                .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
                .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
            End With

        End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably set the height of the ComboBox which can show only a few records and else all the records would be scroll-able

```
ComboBox1.DropDownList.Height
```

you can make 5 items visible for all of the items, by doing something like this:

```
ComboBox1.DropDownList.Height = ComboBox1.Items.Height * 5
```

or

```
ComboBox1.MaxDropDownItems = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.MaxDropDownItems` property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.MaxDropDownItems);k(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox);k(VS.Properties);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true